# s3 bucket object access using identity pool role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have cognito users who have their own object created within one bucket. Within the object the users can add their own files.

I have used the following example and created a role

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

I am struggling on achieving the permissions for the s3 bucket for the cognito users. Basically I am not sure where i need to add the permissions so it will only users with the correct permissions to upload in their own area.

Any suggestions would be great

Thanks

Comment: Replace the bucket and application name in the policy and that should work - what are you exactly asking? Also - which SDK?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. So basically each user needs access to their own bucket so it's setting up the policy for this. Hope that makes sense